# Landscape mode and LinearLayout/ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, landscape

I have tried to make my Android app work in landscape mode but I have failed thus far. Below is the xml code for the layout , and I want to know how to use the `ScrollView` in landscape mode.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android1:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFDEAD"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android1:gravity="center|left|right"
        android1:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number1" ></TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/N1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter number 1"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where's the scrollView?

Comment: Why don't you just put a `ScrollView` around your whole layout? Fixes not only this problem, but also makes your layout useable on small screens. If you don't want that you need to create an extra layout for landscape. More information [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

Comment: @jack i want to add scrollview after making the app works in landscape mode.

Comment: @XaverKapeller how to add the (ScrollView) ?

Comment: i mean where to add the scrollview tags <ScrollView> <\ScrollView>  in the xml code , ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this around your `LinearLayout`?

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout>
        ...
    </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```